# spl_autoload_register unexpected T_FUNCTION

Tags: php, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [unexpected T_FUNCTION with php 5.2.17 but fine on localhost and php 5.3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886282/unexpected-t-function-with-php-5-2-17-but-fine-on-localhost-and-php-5-3-10)

I'm not really used to programming in PHP and it's my first time using an API, so this is how I'm calling it (copy/pasted from their wiki)

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $dir = __DIR__ .'/lib/';
    $file = $dir . strtr($class, '\\', '/') . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require $file;
        return true;
    }
});

use WowApi\Client;
```

When I'm working on localhost on my own computer, everything works perfectly I've got no warning, no error, it works fine. The problem is when I upload this on my FTP I've got the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'
```

Which refers to this line:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
```

I was told to write this in my .htaccess:

```
suPHP_ConfigPath /home/MYUSERNAME/public_html/php.ini
```

and this in my php.ini

```
safe_mode = OFF
```

But unfortunatly nothing works, I still got an error. Do you guys have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous function comes from php 5.3, check the php version of your server. If it is below 5.3, you need to define the function first.

Comment: 5.2.17, it seems that you might be right hehe